# Object properties vs variables

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Having an object with functions, what's a better approach? Using variables or properties of the object?

```
function Panels(){
    var self = this;

    //properties  <-------------
    self.position = 'top';
    self.color = 'black';
    self.numPanels = 0;

    self.addPanel = function(){
        self.numPanels++;
    };

    self.getNumPanels = function(){
        return self.numPanels;
    }
}
```

VS

```
function Panels(){
    var self = this;

    //variables  <-------------
    var position = 'top';
    var color = 'black';
    var numPanels = 0;

    self.addPanel = function(){
        numPanels++;
    };

    self.getNumPanels = function(){
        return numPanels;
    }
}
```

Is it only a matter of making them public and accessible from outside? Or about overriding global variables ?

Comment: the first one may add properties you don't need on each objects

Comment: I think you should spend a little time to read this https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/

Comment: @lonut I did, but it doesn't solve my question.

Comment: Depends on the situation.  Do you need to access them outside of the scope of the constructor function?  Yes?  Use `this`.  No?  `var` is fine.  Global variables don't really come into it.